# onclick submit button, check if an input is empty

Tags: javascript

I've searched and tried just about everything and nothing works.  I'm just trying to have this happen:

onclick a submit button --> check to see if a text field is empty --> if it is, alert an error and do not advance to the next page (if not, advance but only if the values are between 0 - 100 numerically.

Here's what I've got right now (other code I've found that works):

```
<form name="agencytrial">
    <div class="textcenter">
        <input name="AgencyRating" id="AgencyField" type="text" value="" autocomplete="off" class="forceNumeric" onchange="handleChange(this)"; />
        <input class="button" id="FormSubmitButton" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="checkField()";  />
    </div>
</form>

<script>
    function handleChange(input) {
        if (input.value < 0) alert("Value should be between 0 - 100");
        if (input.value > 100) alert("Value should be between 0 - 100");
    }
</script>
```

The above code works fine, and *if* someone types something into the field, and *if* it is not between 0 - 100, then it will alert and error and NOT advance the page.

But *if no one types anything*, they can just click the submit button and advance the page, and the above code does nothing to stop that.  So I tried to use something like the following (one of many attempts):

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function checkField(){
        var x = document.getElementById("AgencyField");
        if (var x = ""){
            alert("Value should be between 0 - 100");
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
</script>
```

The above code fails, and they can just click the submit button and advance without typing anything into the field.

Any help would be majorly appreciated!

**------------EDIT--------------**

**Based on everyone's comments, I've rewritten my code and it's very close.  BUT HERE'S WHAT I DON'T GET:**

**When I input number > 100, it alerts message and DOES NOT ADVANCE.**

**When I leave it blank, it alerts message and ADVANCES.**

**Why the difference?**

```
<form name="agencytrial">
    <div class="textcenter">
        <input name="AgencyRating" id="AgencyField" type="text" value=""   autocomplete="off" class="forceNumeric" onchange="handleChange(this)"/>
        <input class="button" id="FormSubmitButton" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="handleChange()">
    </div>
</form>

<script>
  function handleChange(input){
  var x = document.getElementById("AgencyField").value;
    if (x < 0 || x > 100 || x === "") alert("Value should be between 0 - 100");
    }
</script>
```

**-------EDIT #2--------**

Here's all my code below.  I am just using "form onsubmit" and the "onclick" codes now, as the onchange code was not going to stop the  key or the button from being clicked with the form being empty (i.e., never modified).

I've got the alert popping up with either  or the button being clicked, but the page always advances after I close the alert.

```
<?php
    $compTime = 8;                  // time in seconds to use for 'computer' timing
    if ($text === '') { $text = 'How likely was it that you caused the tone to occur?|Type your response on a scale from 0-100.'; }
    $texts = explode('|', $text);
    $mainText = array_shift($texts);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<form onsubmit="return handleChange();">
    <div class="textcenter">
        <h3><?php echo $mainText; ?></h3>
        <?php
            foreach ($texts as $t) {
                echo '<p>' . $t . '</p>';
            }
        ?>
    </div>

    <div class="textcenter">
        <input name="AgencyRating" id="AgencyField" type="text" value="" autocomplete="off" class="forceNumeric"/>
        <input class="button" id="FormSubmitButton" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return handleChange()"/>
    </div>
</form>

<style type="text/css">
img {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    bottom: -40px;
    left: -21px;
    max-width:520px;
    max-height:520px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
</style>

<body>
<img src="/tapa/Experiment/images/scale.jpg"</img>
</body>
</html>


<script type="text/javascript">
function handleChange(input) {
    var x = document.getElementById("AgencyField").value;
    if (x === "" || x < 0 || x > 100) {
        alert("Value should be between 0 - 100");
        return false;
    }
   return true;
}
</script>
```

*****EDIT*****

I have solved the problem using a new script.  Thanks to everyone and the solutions provided would usually work, but just not in my case for reasons not entirely clear to me but not worth explaining.

Comment: Nothing I try to do works for this.  Literally nothing.  Thanks anyways for all your guys help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated question:

> When I input number > 100, it alerts message and DOES NOT ADVANCE.

When you input a number > `100` and click `submit`, it will trigger the `onchange`. It won't even trigger the submit button.

> When I leave it blank, it alerts message and ADVANCES.

It advances because you don't tell it not to. To do that, you have to return `false` on the `onclick` event (see fix below).

## Fix:

Add `return` to `#FormSubmitButton`'s `onclick`:

```
<input class="button" id="FormSubmitButton" type="submit"
                                            value="Submit" onclick="return handleChange()">
                                                                    ^^^^^^-- add this
```

Add `return`s to the JavaScript function:

```
function handleChange(input) {
    var x = document.getElementById("AgencyField").value;
    if (x < 0 || x > 100 || x === "") {
        alert("Value should be between 0 - 100");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Check [**updated demo fiddle** here](http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/wtjyw884/).

---

## Original question

Several issues:

```
var x = document.getElementById("AgencyField");
```

This way, x only gets a reference to the `#AgencyField` element. You don't want that, you want its value: `var x = document.getElementById("AgencyField").value;`

Also, you are doing an assignment in your `if`, not a comparison:

```
if (var x = ""){
```

This line should be `if (x === ""){`.

Your `function checkField() {` also is missing an ending `}`.

Most important, and subttle, is:

```
<input class="button" id="FormSubmitButton" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="checkField()"; />
```

You should have a `return` there (also remove that `;`):

```
<input class="button" id="FormSubmitButton" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return checkField()"/>
```

All in all, check an **updated** [working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/u54vazsu/2/). There are more changes, they all are shown below (in the comments).

Fixed JavaScript:

```
function handleChange(input) {
    if (input.value.length < 0) { // added .length
        alert("Value should be between 0 - 100");
        return false; // added this
    }
    if (input.value.length > 100-1) { // added .length AND added -1
        alert("Value should be between 0 - 100");
        return false; // added this
    }
    return true; // added this
}

function checkField() {
    var x = document.getElementById("AgencyField").value; // added .value
    if (x === "") { // if (var x = "") -> if (x === "")
        alert("Value should be between 0 - 100");
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
} // added this }
```

Fixed HTML:

```
<form name="agencytrial">
    <div class="textcenter">
        <input name="AgencyRating" id="AgencyField" type="text" value="" autocomplete="off" class="forceNumeric" onkeypress="return handleChange(this)" ; />
        <input class="button" id="FormSubmitButton" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return checkField()" />
    </div>
</form>
<!-- Changes to HTML elements:
#FormSubmitButton
- removed ; at the end
- added return to onclick
#AgencyField
- changed onchange to onkeypress
- added return
-->
```

Comment: Made the changes, and it's giving the alert when the field is blank.  

BUT - the page still advances after I close the alert.  Any thoughts?

Comment: The `onchange` is only triggered when the `input` is blurred. I changed it to `onkeypress`. I also updated the fiddle. Everything should work now. Check it out!

Comment: I appreciate your help.  Check out my main comment now.  I tried your code but it didn't work (still advanced button, and even allowed numbers > 100).

Comment: I updated the answer based on your last question edit. Check it out. See the demo if in doubt.

Comment: What you are saying makes total sense, but I tried it, and it still does the same thing:

Page loads --> I hit submit button --> alert pops up --> I close alert --> page advances.

Comment: Did you add the `return` to the `onclick`? That's the one thing that will prevent the page from advancing. Check the demo fiddle I put there http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/wtjyw884/

Comment: Hi, yes sir, I added it to be:  onclick="return handleChange()"

I've also tried using form onsubmit but that doesn't even reference the function.

The JS Fiddle is doing exactly what I want, but when I put the code into my version and try it, it still advances the page.  

No clue why there is the discrepancy.  Could there be something going on behind the scenes somewhere messing this up?

Comment: Unlikely... I can't think of anything. Something possible would be the declaration of the function *after* it is used, but that doesn't seem to be the problem, since you get the alert...

Comment: Is it alerting and still advancing? Even with the `return true` and `return false` added to the function?

Comment: I got the onsubmit (for the form) thing to work, but still causing the same issue as when it was "onclick".  I really do appreciate all your efforts, I am at least a little closer now, and for that I've very grateful!

Comment: No need to thank at all. How is it now? Can you update the question with the current status and what you are getting and what you would like to get?

Comment: I updated my comment with all my current code.  It always shows the alert, then advances the page.

Comment: What browser do you use? That code seems to work here. Also, your tags are a bit messed up. The `<form>` should be inside `<body>`, the `<script>` should be in `<head>` or right before the end of `<body>`.

Comment: I marked your answer as correct, and I thank everyone for their responses.  It turns out that there were several things occurring in the background which were interfering with the "onsubmit" tag (I am modifying someone else's program).  Anyways, I have a solution now that is different than these, but your solution would work for normal purposes.

So thank you and sorry about all the headache!

Answer (score 2):

You should be using the === sign (not the "=" sign). Right now you are conditionally setting x equal to an empty string, not checking if a value exists.

```
if (var x = ""){
```

But it should look like

```
if (x === ""){
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
    function handleChange(input) {
        if (input.value < 0 || input.value > 100 || isNaN(input.value)) {
           alert("Value should be between 0 - 100");
        }
    }
</script>
```

Why:

[isNan()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) is a Javascript function that returns if given parameter is a number. If it's less than 0 OR more than 100 OR not a number, than the message shows up!

Answer (score 0):

Try onsubmit handler:

```js
var validate = function(form) {
  var agency = +(form.AgencyField.value) || '';
  if (!agency) {
    alert('Agency has to numeric !');
    return false;
  } else if (0 > agency || 100 < agency) {
    alert('Agency must be between 0 - 100');
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
};
```

```html
<form name="agencytrial" onsubmit="return validate(this);">
  <div class="textcenter">
    <input name="AgencyRating" id="AgencyField" type="text" value="" autocomplete="off" class="forceNumeric" />
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution.

```
            <form name="agencytrial" onsubmit="return checkField()">
            <div class="textcenter">
                <input name="AgencyRating" id="AgencyField" type="text" value="" autocomplete="off" class="forceNumeric" onchange="handleChange(this)">
                <input class="button" id="FormSubmitButton" type="submit" value="Submit">
            </div>
            </form>

            <script>
            function handleChange(input) {
              if (!(parseInt(input.value) >= 0 && parseInt(input.value) <= 100)) alert("Value should be between 0 - 100");
            }
            function checkField(){
              var input = document.getElementById("AgencyField");

              if (!(parseInt(input.value) >= 0 && parseInt(input.value) <= 100)) {
                alert("Value should be between 0 - 100")
                return false
              }
              return true
            }
            </script>
```

1. I use `onsubmit` instead of `onclick`.
2. `onsubmit` must return false if you want to do nothing.
3. `parseInt` makes validation easy.

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code to check:

```
<form action = "dashboard.php" onsubmit= "return someJsFunction()">
  <button type="submit" class="button"  id = "submit" name="submit" >Upload to live listing</button>
</form>
    <script type="text/javascript">

       function someJsFunction(){

        const input = document.getElementById('input1');

        if(input.value === ""){
          alert ("no input?"); // This will prevent the Form from submitting
          return false;                              
        }else{
          return true; // this will submit the form and handle the control to php.
        }
     }

</script>
```