# validating the tag input when it is not filled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a tag input it is working but, without entering the value if I click on submit button, it should display an error message like required field

```js
$('#form-tags-4').tagsInput({
  'autocomplete': {
    source: [
      'apple',
      'banana',
      'orange',
      'pizza'
    ]
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/underovsky/jquery-tagsinput-revisited/master/dist/jquery.tagsinput-revisited.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/underovsky/jquery-tagsinput-revisited/master/dist/jquery.tagsinput-revisited.min.js"></script>

<label>Tags input with autocomplete:</label>
<input id="form-tags-4" name="tags-4" type="text" value="">
<button type="submit" id="save" class="btn btn-default ">SAVE</button>
```

Here is the reference [link](https://github.com/underovsky/jquery-tagsinput-revisited)

Comment: u need to write custom js for validation.

Comment: go through this https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you have this error because Chrome (or other browser) can't focus the element. The original text input is hidden by the plugin.

So you get the error :

> An invalid form control with name='tags' is not focusable.

The plugin uses `display: none;` on the original field, which is a mistake I think. You can apply this CSS to have the correct validation message :

```
.form-tags-required {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    display: block !important;
    top: 10px; // depends on your form, adapt it
}
```

This way, the original input can be focused and receive the "required error".

Answer (score 0):

You need to write custom javascript for validation.

```js
 function validateForm()
    {
     
        var a = document.getElementById("form-tags-4").value;
        if (a == "" )
        {
            alert("Please Fill The Required Field");
            return false;
        }
     
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Tags input with autocomplete:</label>
 <input id="form-tags-4" name="tags-4" type="text" value="">
<button type="submit" id="save" class="btn btn-default " onclick="return validateForm()">SAVE</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add form tags and add "required" on input.

```
<form>
   <label>Tags input with autocomplete:</label>
   <input id="form-tags-4" name="tags-4" type="text" value="" required>
   <button type="submit" id="save" class="btn btn-default ">SAVE</button>
</form>
```

[working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/swgbpymh/5/)

Comment: but the tag inputs are not working in the fiddle that you have given

Comment: Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/lakshmipriya001/swgbpymh/25/ that is not working if i give required

Answer (score -1):

You have to add `required='required'` on your `input` first.

After that you must check during `onClick` event the value set and decide if it is right or wrong according to autocomplete source values.

See sample [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32655444/1426086)

Comment: And do you follow the link to implement verification on button click in the aim to validate form ?